# Covariance between sample mean and subsample mean

Tags: self-study, survey-sampling, subsampling

To estimate $\overline{Y}$(population mean), suppose an SRSWOR of size $n$ is taken from a population of size $N$, and the sample mean $\overline{y}$ is calculated. Then an SRSWOR subsample of size $n_1$ is drawn from the first sample and the sample mean $\overline{y_1}$ is calculated. Find $Var(\overline{y_1}-\overline{y})$.

For solving the above, I have got $Var(\overline{y_1})$ and $Var(\overline{y})$, but I don't know how to calculate $Cov(\overline{y_1},\overline{y})$, i.e. I cannot calculate $E(\overline{y_1}*\overline{y})$. Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand  your two mean estimators and do the cross multiplication  and see what happens.

Comment: $E(\overline{y_1})=\overline{y}$ and $E(\overline{y})=\overline{Y}$. So $\overline{y_1}$ is the estimator of $\overline{y}$ and $\overline{y}$ is the estimator of $\overline{Y}$. Where should I do the cross multiplication?

Comment: How do you actually calculate the mean? To be precise, what is $\bar{y}$ exactly?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102620/correlation-of-bootstrap-sample-means

Comment: @Forgottenscience $\bar{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}y_i$